# Canvas dimensions issue in Next.js project: Code vs. Browser Rendering

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, canvas

I'm encountering an issue with the dimensions of a canvas element. Despite setting the width and height attributes to 768px in my code, the canvas element's dimensions in the browser's developer tools show different values (e.g., width="1170" height="617").

Why does this discrepancy occur and how to ensure the canvas element renders with the intended dimensions specified in my code?

```
    <canvas
  ref={canvasRef}
  width={768}
  height={768}
  style={{
    border: "2px solid black",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width: 768,
    height: 768,
  }}
/>
```

Below is the code snippet that represents how the canvas element is rendered in the browser's developer tools:

```
 <canvas width="1170" height="617" style="border: 2px solid black; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 768px; height: 768px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: How is `canvasRef` used? Anything changing its dimensions?